# How to copy production database to another production server - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku, production

I am creating a Rails app for work and until I can install the app on a "in house" server, I am deploying it to Heroku so that we can start using it now. However, I am going to want to be able to copy its database with all of its data over to the final production server when I ready. I am assuming this is somehow possible, but I don't know where to start. Is there a way you can copy a production database (Postgres) from Heroku and move it to a new server to be used there? How would one go about doing this with Rails?

Comment: Couldn't you run production on your local server and then use psql cmds from there? I've made ruby script for dumping sqlite3 dbs, but if you fudge with it you may be able to do something https://gist.github.com/2465154

Comment: check out https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku provides all of this functionality via the [PGBackups](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups) plugins.  There you'll find everything you need to know about importing, exporting, etc...